# Is a Fancybox Considered as New Page in Google Adsense?

Tags: google-adsense

I have a webpage, there are some links that open fancybox.

If a have maximum ads on the webpage, is the fancybox considered as new one?

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu who said anything about an ad blocker? The OP asked about AdSense

Answer (score 2):

Google allow up to 3 adsense in an HTML document, and the fancybox is in the html document (unless you open an iframe inside? or load dynamically new html).

[Google max adsense policy](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1346295#Google_ad_limit_per_page)

Comment: Very true most methods in fancybox are rendering HTML right on the page with the exception of an iframe. Google may even recognize an iframe though it'd be interesting to test but i'm sure against their TOS.